# How to join scatterplots together using ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to join scatterplots together in one table of data:

The data is:

```
row   Var1      Var2 Freq
1     0        Good      17
2     1        Good     479
3     2        Good     455
4     3        Good     273
5     4        Good     155
6     5        Good       9
7     0        Average   81
8     1        Average 2449
9     2        Average 4627
10    3        Average 3261
11    4        Average 3142
12    5        Average  110
13    0        Bad      74
14    1        Bad      1472
15    2        Bad      3881
16    3        Bad      3399
17    4        Bad      5431
18    5        Bad      188
```

Joining together in the following format is a problem since I can't join lines and get a chart as attached. I want the different scatter plots linked together[image]
(edit)The code for the plot is below:

```
   ggplot(dfs, aes(Var1, Freq, colour=Var2))+geom_line()+geom_point()
```

The result should look something like (that I have successfully joined - the same data but using another Var1 as the x axis):
[image]

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: Placed chart - its actually the same data set but using different axis

Comment: Your code works fine for me (R 3.1.2 & ggplot2 1.0.1 on Mac OSX). So, what is the problem?

Comment: You could try using `aes(..., group=var2)`